# Execute command in another terminal and closing it without killing command

Tags: bash, command, gnome-terminal

For closing terminal without killing script/command we use `&` operator at last while calling command. Like:

```
gedit &
```

<sub>Here I used `gedit` as an example command</sub>

Same thing I want to do on another terminal (from current terminal). I am using following command(s) to run script/command onto another terminal:

- `gnome-terminal -e 'gedit'`
- `gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'gedit'`

But here if I close **new opened terminal**, then script/program runnung by `[command]` also killed. So I've tried using `&` as follows:

- `gnome-terminal -e 'gedit' &`
- `gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'gedit' &`

But none of above is working.

So, How can I achieve this : From current `gnome-terminal`, Execute command in another `gnome-terminal` and close that (new-opened) terminal after launching command without killing running `command`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining **`nohup`** & **`screen`**, Al last I achieved what I want.

By [kirill-a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/24516/kirill-a), the command : `gnome-terminal -e "nohup bash gedit"` is suggested.

However by using above command, I can run command and can close new opened `gnome-terminal` without killing running command, **BUT** I've to manually close new opened `gnome-terminal` window. And I want it to be closed automatically after launching command.

By [Dimitar Dimitrov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/98856/dimitar-dimitrov) `screen` command is suggested.

At-last I used `screen` with `nohup` and my **Final command becomes:**

- **`gnome-terminal -e 'screen nohup gedit'`**
- **`gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'screen nohup gedit'`**

By using either of above command(s) I get: ***command launched in new terminal window and after launching command, new opened terminal closed without killing running command.***

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nohup` command - it disconnects the process from the terminal, so even if you close the gnome-terminal window, it will continue to run.

Example: `gnome-terminal -e "nohup bash gedit"`

Comment: Yes this command is working, But I've to manually close new opened `gnome-terminal` window. I want that it will be automatically closed after launching command (`gedit`).

Comment: Than you for suggesting `nohup` that will help me to solve my problem and I write [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178715/66803)

Answer (score 1):

You can user screen utility. Screen is  a  full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes (typically interactive shells - for more details execute `man screen`.

As soon as you execute the screen command in the shell a new window with a shell in it will be created. You can execute whatever command/script/daemon you want. You can easily detach from the window using the key shortcut: Ctrl+A+D.

To list all sessions you have started you can use `screen -list`. You can attach to the lastly detached session using `screen -r` or if you want to attach on a particular session use `screen -r <host.tty>`.

Example:

```
[root@dns-ldap ~]# screen -list
There are screens on:
        5708.pts-0.dns-ldap     (Detached)
        5648.pts-0.dns-ldap     (Detached)
        5725.pts-0.dns-ldap     (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.

[root@dns-ldap ~]# screen -r 5708.pts-0.dns-ldap #this will attach you to terminal 5708.pts-0.dns-lda. I have detached from the terminal usinc Ctrl+A+D
[detached]
[root@dns-ldap ~]# screen -r 5648.pts-0.dns-ldap
[detached]
[root@dns-ldap ~]#
```

Comment: Your `screen` command also help me to find [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178715/66803)